# remove the highlight for the current parenthesis but keep it for the matching pair

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, parentheses

When I work in a fast paced with vim, one of the recurring annoyance is highlighting of {} or {} or []. When the parenthesis or brackets are adjacent to each other, it takes me a second (yes a whole second!) to figure out where the focus is. I do not like having to rely on the blinking and I still want the matching paren/bracket to be highlighted. So how can I remove just the highlighting for the current paren/bracket?

Answer (score 1):

```
:hi MatchParen ctermbg=black guibg=black
```

show match is ok, but the highlight was driving me nutz.  The above turns the highight black so you don't see it when editor has a black background

Answer (score 0):

`:NoMatchParen`

type `:help matchparen` for more help on this .

this functionnality is really useful for me, so maybe you can look at the doc a little and find a way to hightlight the matching pair in a different color (or just underline it for example)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is

`set noshowmatch`

to be set in vimrc